# On hook_form_alter setting select list options for a field

Tags: 7, nodes, forms

By default select options i have left empty in admin of that content type.

I am trying to alter select list option of a content type using hook_form_alter.

I am setting the values to select values and is getting assigned.

Only issue is that its **getting logged out** with single refresh to create form of that content type form or try to submit that form. What am i doing wrong in the code.

Thanks in advance.

```
function hook_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id)
{
    if($form_id == 'product_node_form')
    {       

            $users = db_select('users', 'u');
            $users->join('users_roles','ur','u.uid = ur.uid');
            $users->fields('u',array('name'));
            $users->fields('ur',array('uid'));
            $users->condition('ur.rid',6,'=');
            $users->orderBy('u.uid');
            $users = $users->execute()->fetchAll();

            $vendor_list = array("Tan" => "Tan");

            foreach($users as $key => $user)
            {
                $vendor_list[$user->name] = $user->name;
            }
            $form['field_publish_to']['und']['#options'] = $vendor_list;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to rename the variable **$user**/ **$users**. May be your code is overwriting the default $user object of drupal. Try after renaming the variables **$user**/ **$users**.

Comment: You have nailed it.That was the issue variable $users/$user was the real issue.

Comment: If the OP showed all the code they are using, this should not be the case, since there isn't a `GLOBAL $user;` line.